# timeout handling with web request using async await

Tags: c#, timeout, async-await, c#-5.0

In this walkthrough:

```
       http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh300224.aspx
```

how would the asynchronous approach be modified to handle timeout scenarios?

```
     using (WebResponse response = await req.GetResponseAsync())
     {

     }
```

Or would a different approach have to be taken?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do `async` HTTP requests is to use `HttpClient` rather than `WebRequest`, and `HttpClient` has a [`Timeout` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout.aspx) you can set.

Comment: Is there a walkthrough or blog post you might suggest, Stephen? I've been going in circles on this for several days, running into deprecated solutions that don't take advantage of C#5.0. I'm hoping to find an example that performs an async web request, handles timeout, and updates the UI after each such request with a status (good, bad, timed-out). Eventually I want to issue such requests in a tight loop, so that many of them can be active concurrently. I'm checking a database of 100K urls to see which ones are good/moved/slow.

Comment: I'm not aware of any resource like that. It seems like it wouldn't be hard to program, though; just define an `async` helper method to handle the exceptions and translate them to an appropriate return value.

Comment: The advantage I saw to the WebRequest is that it has a HEAD method, and I couldn't find the counterpart to that in the HttpClient. But I've since found it: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/14b3ee11-0492-4111-b6c5-217b5fcf0a2e/sending-a-http-head-request-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Set the [Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.timeout.aspx) property on the `WebRequest` object

Comment: Which [only applies to synchronous calls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout.aspx).

Comment: Oh, that is sad - my bad :(

Comment: But i'll keep my answer here so that no one else makes same mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Follow a solution to respect the timeout

```
await Task.Run(() => {
   var varHttpResponse = varWebRequest.GetResponse();
});
```